# Pythonista 3 doesn’t show iCloud files created on MacBook Pro

Tags: python, icloud, pythonista

Description:

- Using the menu `Script Library > iCloud` in Pythonista 3 on iPad shows .py files created in Pythonista, but not files created in another IDE and saved to that iCloud folder

Steps to reproduce:

- create .py file in an IDE on MacBook Pro
- save the file on MacBook Pro in `iCloud > Pythonista 3 > <subfolder>`
- in Pythonista 3 on iPad, open the main menu (hamburger menu) and select `Script Library > iCloud >

Expected:

- Pythonista file navigator shows all files in the folder

Actual:

- Pythonista file navigator shows only the files created in Pythonista

Questions:

- Is Pythonista caching an index of its iCloud folder separately? If so, is there a way to get Pythonista to reindex the folder?
- How to see all the files in the Pythonista iCloud folder, and thus use that folder for syncing files between iPad and MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 2):

You can also open the files in Pythonista using the "Files" app from Apple on the same device. Once you opened them this way, they usually show up in Pythonista´s file browser/open file menu just fine. That way you don't have to go through the hassle of doing this on another iOS device and the sharing... .

Answer (score 0):

Problem:

- Pythonista does seem to be either a) relying on an outdated index of the `iCloud > Pythonista` folder itself, or b) not downloading the files from iCloud automatically. We need to force Pythonista to fetch the file details directly and/or download the files.

Solution:

- Under the main menu (hamburger menu), click the `+`, then `Import...`, and select `Files` from the contextual menu. This will access the iCloud drive.
- Select the Pythonista folder from iCloud.

This should trigger Pythonista to download the current files from iCloud. You won’t need to actually complete the import procedure - it’s enough to access the iCloud drive through the import menu.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with .pyui files. The .pyui files show in the "Import..." file list but are greyed out and cannot be imported.

Comment: 5 minutes later, I found one workaround on the omz forums. Open the .pyui file in the Files app on another iOS device and share it with the iOS with pythonista.